# Is this version of Spring repos too old to take advantage of latest rest controller and autowiring etc?

Tags: java, spring

I am stuck using this version due to licensing
'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE'
So would like to create a rest controller and impl that implements a repo that extends jpa repo so I have all the cool stuff with autowiring/automagically save/pagination etc etc.

Is this gonna be a problem with this version? Anyone know what wont work with it?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)

Comment: Licensing? It is open source there is, apart from the apache license, no other license. Also why create an interface and do the implenetation of that? Seems to beat the purpose of Spring Data...